# Integrated data from two services

Tags: node.js, integrated

I'm developing a note app. There's a requirements for integrated data from a number of services (such as gist, evernote,...) through its api.

Each system have its own `scheme` for note, ([gist](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-single-gist) [evernote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote)), how can I map these scheme for my own scheme `Note`.

Are there any `nodejs` package available for this task?

PS: For create scheme, I use [`mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/)

Comment: You will have to look into the schema (design) of all the services you want to integrate and decide what final structure should be for your system. Once this is decided then mongoose is technically the best choice to shape it as Schema. Attributes selection is to be done manually.

Comment: I decided my schema.

Next tasks, I want pull user's notes from gist to my server, integrate with user's in my server. And when user create a note, it automatically push it to gist server. And I wil treat other services like this one. So I want a package (something like mapper), two ways convert between two schema (which defined by mongoose, or other scheme package). For communicate with rest services, I want a package (something like ngResource).

In node world, are these packages available?